# How can I enable cluster.indices.close.enable temporarily on Elastic Cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch

The document(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/external/cluster-config.html#user-settings) says

> You might enable this setting temporarily in order to change the analyzer configuration for an existing index.

But I can't find how to do that.

How can I enable cluster.indices.close.enable temporarily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a setting to modify in your User settings panel, see this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-change-user-settings.html):

1. Log into the Cloud UI.
2. Click on a cluster name from the Clusters panel and click Edit icon.
3. In the User Settings section, update the user settings.
4. Click Save changes.

As @ZerefeL mentions in the comment, you might have to wait up to 10 minutes for the config to be properly updated.

Comment: For anyone (like me) wondering why it doesn't work at first - when updating a cluster's settings, give it some time to properly reflect the config change. In my case it took 5-10 minutes.

Comment: @ZerefeL Thanks for the precision I updated my answer based on that